# How do you test a DNS domain transfer using OpenSRS?

Tags: domain-name-system

How do you test doing a domain transfer to your domain registry using OpenSRS without using a real domain owned by some other registrar? Is there a test domain that is available for doing transfers?

Answer (score 1):

OpenSRS has a test system available at http://horizon.opensrs.net

You should be using that for testing.

Answer (score 0):

By guessing I found out that exampledomain.com is available for transfers.

Comment: Glad you resolved this issue. Please be sure to mark your answer as "accepted" when you are able.